# Magento SSL connect error

Tags: magento, ssl, ssh, installation, upgrade

When I try to install a plugin through Magento Connect or try to upgrade Magento through SSH, I get an SSL Connect Error. I can't find a proper solution. Who can help me out?

[image: Magento Connect error]

[image: SSH Error]

Comment: Same here... any ideas? I'm using 1.9.2.4... It hapens on the previous install's as well, where a week ago it worked perfectly.